# How to display animation image like the Quick Search Box

Tags: android, user-interface

I have implemented an activity that retrieves data from a web service and display it in the AutoCompleteTextView. This has been working quite well.

I'm interested in displaying a spinning animation while the data is being retrieved (The same effect like the Quick Search Box)

I try to figure out how the QSB is doing it (10x Open Source!) but couldn't find any place where the spinner image is being put/set/drawn onto the EditText control.

[alt text http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/8210/spinnera.png](http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/8210/spinnera.png)

Comment: You may be able to define the spinner as `android:drawableRight` on the `EditText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public interface to set the 'working spinner'.

If you implemented the suggestion provider, the spinner shows when the query starts.

[Reference](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/app/SuggestionsAdapter.java;h=8d8864f34b369b2aea3895abe4dade9d482f2ea6;hb=HEAD#l150)